# Can't insert range to google sheets in Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I have Array with data 
`table_data = [["11"],["22"]],[["33"],["44"]]`
And I want to insert this data into Google Sheets using sheet.values().update, but with GridRange, without Named Range
I have the resolve for this:

```
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds())
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    body = {'values': values}
    SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME_2 = 'costs!A1:B2'
    value_input_option = 'RAW'
    result = sheet.values().update(
        spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME_2, valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=body).execute()
```

But it's unconvinient use with range A1:B2. I want to use something like this

```
'startColumnIndex': 0,
'endColumnIndex': 1,
'startRowIndex': 0,
'endRowIndex': 1
```

I try use batchUpdate for this, but it can accept only string parameter

```
spreadsheet_id = SPREADSHEET_ID  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body = {
        "requests": [
            {
                "pasteData": {
                    "data": str(table_data),
                    "type": "PASTE_NORMAL",
                    "delimiter": ",",
                    "coordinate": {
                        "sheetId": 0,
                        "rowIndex": 0,
                        "columnIndex": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body)
response = request.execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to put values using GridRange.
- You want to use `table_data = [["11"],["22"]],[["33"],["44"]]` as the value.

  - I think that if you want to put the values with 2 rows and 2 columns, it becomes `table_data = [["11", "22"], ["33", "44"]]`. So I used this.
  - If you want to put 11, 22, 33 and 44 to A1, B1, A2 and B2, respectively, it becomes `table_data = [["11", "22"], ["33", "44"]]`.
  - If you want to put 11, 22, 33 and 44 to A1, A2, B1 and B2, respectively, it becomes `table_data = [["11", "33"], ["22", "44"]]`.

If my understanding is correct, how about using the method of "updateCells" of batchUpdate instead of "pasteData"? I think that there are several solutions for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

#### Modified script:

```
spreadsheet_id = SPREADSHEET_ID
sheetId = 0
table_data = [["11", "33"], ["22", "44"]]  # or table_data = [["11", "22"], ["33", "44"]]
rows = [{'values': [{'userEnteredValue': {'stringValue': f}} for f in e]} for e in table_data]
rng = {'sheetId': sheetId, 'startRowIndex': 0, 'startColumnIndex': 0}
fields = 'userEnteredValue'
body = {'requests': [{'updateCells': {'rows': rows, 'range': rng, 'fields': fields}}]}
request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body)
response = request.execute()
```

- When the values are put to `A1:B2`, you can set the coordinate of the top left cell. So in this case, the GridRange becomes `{'sheetId': sheetId, 'startRowIndex': 0, 'startColumnIndex': 0}`

#### Note:

- If you want to use `table_data = [["11"], ["22"]], [["33"], ["44"]]`, please modify `rows` to `rows = [{'values': [{'userEnteredValue': {'stringValue': f[0]}} for f in e]} for e in table_data]`.

#### Reference:

- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Please tell me, is it working with huge qty of cells? Because when I want to past data from list to cell in the loop - it takes long time...

Comment: @Zzema Thank you for replying. About ``huge qty of cells``, I couldn't notice about the number of values you use from your question. I apologize for my poor English skill. About the limitation, when the used cells are closed to 5 million cells, an error occurs and/or the process time becomes long. About the cost of Sheets API, when I have measured it, the costs of 4 methods of ``batchUpdate``, ``values.update``, ``values.batchUpdate`` and ``values.append`` of Sheets API which is used for writing values were almost the same.

Comment: @Zzema So as a method, at first, create the request body including values, and then send it by one API call. If the values cannot be sent by one API call, it is required to split the values and send them by several API calls. If the number of used cells is over 5 million cells, it is required to split the values and put them to other Spreadsheet. But if I misunderstand your question and my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize.

Comment: I am trying to use it, but it's only for string 'stringValue': f
what I may do, if some columns have digits?

Comment: @Zzema If you want to put the formulas and numbers, also you can do it. You can see the document at [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#ExtendedValue).